# How to pass json/list values to a template in HEAT user_data

Tags: openstack, openstack-heat

need to replace user_data with dynamic values in resource group from comma_delimited_list.

%index% is not working.

```
heat_template_version: 2015-10-15

test_parameter:
type: comma_delimited_list
label: test param  list
description: test descr
default: 'test_param_1,test_param_2'
.......
...... 

type: OS::Heat::ResourceGroup
properties:
.........
.........
user_data:
    str_replace:
      template: |
        get the local value of the instance : $val
      params:
        $val: { get_param: [ test_parameter, %index% ] }
```

How to pass json/list values to a template in HEAT-user_data

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, aws-cloudformation-based is still somewhat limited to what you can normally do, and heat-specific language (that is still based on aws-cloudformation) is bound by the same limitations.

Normally, the best solutions you can have is have a "selection" lists on the top of your template, and pass some of the selections to your resources. In the following example, one of those selections ask's for a specific web-app to install (from nginx and apache), and pass this as a variable to the user-data section of your template:

```
heat_template_version: 2015-04-30

description: >
  Hello world HOT template that just defines a single server.
  Contains just base features to verify base HOT support.

parameters:
  key_name:
    type: string
    description: Name of an existing key pair to use for the server
    default: "topcat-01"
    constraints:
      - custom_constraint: nova.keypair
  flavor:
    type: string
    description: Flavor for the server to be created
    default: m1.normal
    constraints:
      - custom_constraint: nova.flavor
  image:
    type: string
    description: Image ID or image name to use for the server
    default: Ubuntu-1404lts-32-Cloud
    constraints:
      - custom_constraint: glance.image
  my_network:
    type: string
    description: Neutron Network
    default: public-internet-access
    constraints:
      - custom_constraint: neutron.network
  application-install:
    type: string
    default: apache
    constraints: 
      - allowed_values: [apache, nginx]
        description: Value must be one of 'apache', or 'nginx'

resources:
  server:
    type: OS::Nova::Server
    properties:
      key_name: { get_param: key_name }
      image: { get_param: image }
      flavor: { get_param: flavor }
      security_groups: 
        - default
      name: test-single-topcat-instance
      networks:
        - network: { get_param: my_network }
      user_data_format: RAW
      user_data:
        str_replace:
          template: |
            #!/bin/bash
            myapp="$selectedapp01"
            echo "MY APP IS $myapp"
            PATH=$PATH:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
            case $myapp in
            apache)
                echo "INSTALLING APACHE"
                if [ -f /etc/debian_version ]
                then
                   aptitude -y update
                   aptitude -y install apache2
                fi
                if [ -f /etc/redhat-release ]
                then
                   yum -y install httpd
                   chkconfig httpd on
                   echo "" >> /var/www/html/index.html
                   service httpd start
                fi
                ;;
            nginx)
                echo "INSTALLING NGINX"
                if [ -f /etc/debian_version ]
                then
                   aptitude -y update
                   aptitude -y install nginx-full
                fi
                if [ -f /etc/redhat-release ]
                then
                   yum -y install nginx
                   chkconfig nginx on
                   service nginx start
                fi
                ;;
            esac
          params:
            $selectedapp01: {get_param: application-install}

outputs:
  server_networks:
    description: The networks of the deployed server
    value: { get_attr: [server, networks] }
```

From the example above, the "application-install" parameter (which can be either apache or nginx) will be interpreted as "$selectedapp01" at the end of the user-data section, and as "$myapp" (myapp="$selectedapp01") at the beginning of the user-data.

It is not perfect, but is the normal way to go. Most cloudformation-deploying tools construct the final template from a set of "questions-and-answers" and you finished with a static (of semistatic) template.

This one I added here as example, will ask you for many things and set some defaults.

Hope it helps.